# O @using da minha view não encontra o model no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, namespace, model

[[image: @using]

Olá amigos meu nome é Wesley eu já faço programa a algum tempo (huahuahua) sempre uso a plataforma para tirar duvidas mas é a primeira vez que uso a plataforma para perguntar, espero que possam me ajudar estou criando uma aplicação em Asp.net MVC utilizando o Visual Studio 2017, iniciei com o template vazio comecei modelar minha classe, meu controller mas quando vou para a view e procuro o List Model "Custos" com o @using não encontra apresentando o seguinte erro: "O nome do tipo ou do namespace "Custos" não pode ser encontrado(está faltando uma diretiva using ou uma referencia de assembly)", já tentei adicionar todas as referencias assemblies possíveis e não funcionou, desde já agradeço a todos...

Answer (score 0):

Antes do seu @model, adicione o caminho onde está esta classe em seu projeto, exemplo:

@using Exportacao.Modelos

Tente também dar um rebuild em todo seu projeto, e em último caso fechar e abrir o visual studio novamente.

Comment: eu já tentei usar o @using Exportação.Models antes do model List<Custos> na view mas não deu certo também a view ainda não achou a minha classe "Custos" acredito que eu deva adicionar uma referencia em assemblies mas já tentei adicionar de tudo e não foi :(

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, Wel!

Você precisa adicionar o `namespace` dessa classe no arquivo `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using Nomedoprojeto.Models.ViewModels
```